# Как использовать один массив в разных кнопках, но чтобы изначальный не менялся(c# - windows forms)

Tags: c#

у меня есть кнопка которая создает массив, как мне сделать ,чтобы когда я в другой кнопке изменял его(например находил мин.число и заменял все отриц числа) он выводил результат, и потом я нажимаю другую кнопку которая делает операции наоборот и чтобы она работала с исходным ,а не уже измененным .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Допустим у вас есть массив

```
int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

Можно сделать его копию вот так

```
int[] clone = (int[])array.Clone();
```

[Документация](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.array.clone)